# The localhost page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request in cakephp 3.4

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4

I'm using apache server to run my cakephp 3.4 version application on ubuntu, I'm getting strange problem as below

> > The localhost page isn’t working
> >
> > localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
> >     HTTP ERROR 500

But It's working fine in 3.3 version app. does anyone have idea about it?

Comment: is there something in your error logs?

Comment: where do I find error logs?

Comment: got error logs. yeah something is there in error log

Comment: Then please show what's in there, nobody here will be able to help you without seeing the actual errors.